# Excel formula where certain combinations of cells would return a value

Tags: excel

I'm creating a stakeholder map and I have two columns with two possible entries for each

```
Power | Interest | Strategy
```

Power and Interest can be either High or Low

So I am trying to get a strategy to return a value based on whether Power or Interest is one of those two combinations as an example:

```
Power = High, Interest = High, Strategy = Manage Closely
Power = Low, Interest = High, Strategy = Keep Informed
Power = Low, Interest = Low, Strategy = Monitor
Power = High, Interest = Low, Strategy = Meet Their Needs
```

Can someone help me with this formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a long way is to use if() with AND() like so:

[image]

```
IF(AND(B1="high",D1="High"),"Manage closely",IF(AND(B1="Low",D1="High"),"Keep informed",IF(AND(B1="Low",D1="Low"),"Monitor",IF(AND(B1="high",D1="Low"),"Meet their needs"))))
```

But a table with vlookup() is easier to control as per the other answer. However, this does not use a helper column...

Answer (score 2):

Make a new column where you concatenate Power and interest.

```
  A     B           C            D
1 Power Interest    Concat       Result
2 High  Low         HighLow       
3 High  High        HighHigh
```

Then somewhere down in the excel (or in another tab) make a relationship between inputs and outputs

```
     A      B           C           D
1000 Power  Interest    Concat      Result
1001 High   High        HighHigh    Manage Closely
1002 High   Low         HighLow     Kep Informed
1003 Low    High        LowHigh     Monitor
1004 Low    Low         LowLow      Meet Their Needs
```

finally use the following formula in the cell D2 and slide it down to all your rows

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,$C$1001:$D$1004,2)
```

Where C is the concatenated column, C1001:D1004 is the relationship table location.

You can then hide the column C if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this formula and it worked for me:

```
=IF(AND(A2="High";B2="High");"Manage Closely"; IF(AND(A2="Low";B3="High");"Keep Informed"; IF(AND(A2="Low";B2="Low");"Monitor"; IF(AND(A2="High";B2="Low");"Meet Their Needs";0))))
```

Drag down/Copy and paste the formula under the Strategy Column and it should turn out like this:

[image]

Comment: This one did not work for me, I got an error, thanks for the assistance

Comment: @RickCabrera you might be getting the error because of the semicolon used change it to comma that should work as well `=IF(AND(A2="High";B2="High");"Manage Closely"; IF(AND(A2="Low";B3="High");"Keep Informed"; IF(AND(A2="Low";B2="Low");"Monitor"; IF(AND(A2="High";B2="Low");"Meet Their Needs";0))))
`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:
You can use built-in function below after saving your file as an .xlsm file and saving the code in a new module in file:

[image]

```
    Function myStrategy(power As String, Interest As String) As String
    
    If LCase(power) = "high" And LCase(Interest) = "high" Then
    myStrategy = "Manage Closely"
    ElseIf LCase(power) = "low" And LCase(Interest) = "high" Then
    myStrategy = "Keep Informed"
    ElseIf LCase(power) = "low" And LCase(Interest) = "low" Then
    myStrategy = "Monitor"
    ElseIf LCase(power) = "high" And LCase(Interest) = "low" Then
    myStrategy = "Meet Their Needs"
    End If
    
    End Function
```